# GN: What would this legacy "snow" setup look like in 3.0+?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm looking over a CG Cookie post from last year when 2.93 was released and there is [a section dedicated to Geometry Nodes](https://cgcookie.com/posts/all-the-new-features-and-changes-in-blender-2-93#question_3) with a node tree I would like to recreate. But it uses nodes that are now legacy. What would the 3.0+ solution be to get the following effect:

[image: A snow-like proximity effect created with Geometry Nodes in Blender 2.93]

[image: Snow proximity effect's node tree in Blender 2.93 using legacy nodes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Try this (Blender 3.2):

Just replace the Attribute nodes with regular Field nodes:

[image: Snow Geonodes Setup]

Comment: Thank you for this! I've been playing around with it and have realized there is a lot of room for experimentation between **Geometry Proximity** and **Set Position**. Examples: Setting the **Math** node to *Tangent*, dropping in an **RGB Curves** node, or plugging a **Normal** node into the **Vector Math** node's second socket so that it works on sloped surfaces too. Good stuff.

Comment: @Mentalist the **Normal** node is a great idea! I also found that adding a **Power** node before the **Multiply** and messing with the **Map Range** some more created a nice curved falloff instead of the ugly linear one.